# How to change/update timeseriechart name (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

Created a timeserieschart and update it every 10 secondes with a timer.
But has a problem to update the title of a the chart.
When I call : chart.setTitle(name) the error appears : "The method setTitle(String) is undefined for the type Chart".
with chart.setName(name) no error but does not update the chart title.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Java is case sensitive; perhaps you meant `chart.setTitle()`.

Comment: I know as stated the line showing the error is : chart.setTitle(name);

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows he error.

Comment: Problem solved I was trying to rename the class Chart which extends JPanel instead of the chart (timeseriechart). Thank you anyway. –

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I was trying to rename the class Chart which extends JPanel instead of the chart (timeseriechart). I created a method which take argument as string in my class Chart where the timeseriechart is created and easily in the method I called : chart.setTitle(name). Finally the new created method is called where is needed.